# 18.04 shuts off immediately after login

Tags: boot, 18.04, crash

I just recently Installed Ubuntu 18.04 on an msi laptop. The bootable usb worked fine, connected to wifi and everything. I can boot to the newly installed os on my hard drive too, but right after I enter my login information and press enter, it completely crashes with no error message or anything. I've tried reinstalling it twice now.

**Edit:**
*Ctrl+alt+f3* allows me to login without error, but I still cannot switch back over to the GUI with `startx`

Comment: did you have crash when you try to log in in tty mode? use **Ctrl** + **Alt** + **F1** to be in this mode, and **Ctrl** + **Alt** + **F7** to return in graphical mode (or `startx` command)

Comment: @damadam im able to login fine with ctrl+alt+f3, but as soon as I try the command "startx" it crashes.

Comment: please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1183511/edit) your answer with this new information, so it must be an issue with **startx** or **gnome-desktop**

Comment: does your issue solved? if yes, write your own answer

Answer (score 2):

After searching for a graphics driver using `$ apt search nvidia-driver` I was able to find the driver I needed and install it using `$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430`